# php upload pdf, doc, docx

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I am try to upload files to my server the allowed extension should be pdf, doc, docx 
this is my code.

```
$uploadCv = $_FILES['uploadCv']['name'];
    $target = "includes/employeeCv/";
    $target = $target . basename($_FILES['uploadCv']['name']);
    if ($_FILES['uploadCv']['size'] == 0) {
        $error['uploadCvErr'] = "<span class='notAllowed'>Please upload your c.v</span>";
    } elseif
    (
        $_FILES['uploadCv']['type'] != 'application/pdf'
        && $_FILES['uploadCv']['type'] != 'application/msword'
        && $_FILES['uploadCv']['type'] != 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    ) {
        $error['uploadCvErr'] = 'Unsupported file type uploaded.';
    } elseif ($_FILES['uploadCv']['size'] > 5000000) {
        $error['uploadCvErr'] = 'File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.';
    }
```

everything is going OK with PDF and doc but on docx it says `Unsupported file type uploaded.`

what I am doing wrong here.

**Edit**
I added this to my check files
`&& $_FILES['uploadCv']['type'] != 'application/zip'`
still not working.

Comment: echo the `type` of the file, its not what you think it is

Comment: @Dagon what should I do to solve this problem

Comment: Mr B. below gave you the answer

Comment: OK I just add this `&& $_FILES['uploadCv']['type'] != 'application/zip'` to my code but still not working is this what you mean

Comment: echo the type and see what is returned

Comment: var_dump `array(1) { ["uploadCv"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(16) "This is any.docx" ["type"]=> string(35) "application/vnd.ms-word.document.12" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpvqr4sx" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(11408) } } `

Comment: well that explains it. type is "application/vnd.ms-word.document.12"

Comment: Thanks very much @Dagon for you efforts yes this was the solution worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OfficeOpenXML `.docx` files often have the `application/zip` mime type because they are a zipped collection of XML files, and browsers are too lazy to check beyond the zip signature when setting mime type

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but what is the solution what should I do?

Comment: The solution is to check for a mime type of `application/zip` as well... if you want to be more strict, then you can open the ziparchive and check for the presence of certain files inside the zip

Comment: Of course, simply testing the mime type passed in with the request isn't the most secure method anyway, because a browser/request can send whatever it wants

Comment: I am try to understand how to check for a mime type of `application/zip`.

Comment: so you mean I have to just add `$_FILES['uploadCv']['type'] != 'application/zip'` this to my code?